# Did I blow my engine with too much oil?

Tags: engine, lawnmower, tractor

I recently changed the oil and filter on my 2007 Sears tractor.  I put in 64 oz as instructed.  The tractor ran about 45 minutes, I mowed the lawn. No problems.  3 days later I went to mow again, and after a couple of minutes, it sounded like a gunfire and a massive amount of white smoke filled the air.  It is dead now.  I get nothing when I turn the key.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What model tractor? What engine do you have? Who instructed you to add 64 oz? Did you check the oil level before you started it the last time? When you say dead, it engine doesn't even try to turn? Is there any noise at all? Is there any oil leaking out?

Comment: If you check the oil "level" what reading do you get?  Also, what engine do you have on your tractor?  (I have been around allot of mower engines, and seldom do they need 64 oz of oil, and even then it is usually with a higher priced diesel engine.)

Answer (score 1):

My tractor friend diagnosed my problem after listening to what I had to say in less than 2 minutes.   I used my manual for the amount of oil.  The manual is incorrect, the proper amount in written inside the engine cover. I definitely added too much....... the key was dead, because he said, too much engine oil, I was going up a small incline which pushed the oil into the crackcase(?). That made it blow......  the blow,...blew Crap and smoke onto the key sensor on the lower side of the engine.  He just wiped that off.   I drained the extra oil out, and all is well!!!  He saved me the price of a new tractor.     Thank you all.